# Swap views or swap activites as a subsection of my layout?

Tags: android, view, android-activity, switching

I've created a custom navigation bar for my application.  One of the things it (currently) does is allow you to switch between various activities in the application.  One part I still have yet to solve fully is how to keep the navigation bar constant on the UI while the view above it switches to another activity.

[This google groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/b61a126495cfcddc) seems to ask this very question and the solution seems to revolve around using a LocalActivityManager to add the Window decor of the new activity to a ViewGroup of your current layout.  I'm curious if anyone has done this before and what their thoughts were?

In particular I'd be interested in the pros/cons of the LocalActivityManager/multiple activities approach vs one super activity which switches multiple views (rather than activities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that Fragments would be the recommended way to accomplish this now: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html They have a lifecycle like activities but are meant to be added and removed from layouts. With the compatibility library (http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/fragments-for-all.html) you can use them all the way back to OS v1.6. As a bonus this is the way that the OS has been moving in terms of reusable UI components since v3.0, so you should be in better shape for the future.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I had discovered Fragments during my investigations but put them aside as not being compatible with pre v3.  The compatibility library looks interesting.